# Node.js Version of InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mustache

I'm trying to loop through some items and create HTML to pass through to the view file:

```
const itemWrap = '<div id="items"></div>';

    userDetails.notes.forEach(item => { 

      const itemElement = '<div class="item"><span>'+item+'</span></div>';

      itemWrap.innerHTML(itemElement);

    });
```

I'm getting an error **itemWrap.innerHTML is not a function**. I realized Node.js is server not browser so is there an alternative to innerHTML to achieve this?

I'm using Node + Express + Mustache

Comment: Well, [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not a function, even in the browser. Try using it as a property (i.e., `itemWrap.innerHTML = itemElement;`) to see if that works.

Comment: `itemWrap` is a string in your code. Unless you use a parser to HTML'ify it, you cannot use HTML-style properties and functions on it.

Comment: [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/intro) might be a good bet.

Comment: This code wouldn't even work in the browser. `itemWrap` is a simple string - trying to change the `innerHTML` of it wouldn't work. Especially because `innerHTML` isn't a method on DOM elements (it's a property) but also because a string isn't a DOM element.

Comment: Can you share the expected result?

Comment: "Mustache" — If you're using Mustache why are you mashing strings of HTML together in JS instead of using the Mustache feature designed for it? https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#:~:text=When%20the%20value%20is%20a%20non%2Dempty%20list%2C%20the%20text%20in%20the%20block%20will%20be%20displayed%20once%20for%20each%20item%20in%20the%20list.

Comment: First few hours learning Mustache... rookie mistake. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking to use Mustache, and it is fine if the HTML remains just a string that you will later send to a browser, the following Mustache template would achieve what you are trying to do:

```
<div id="items">
    {{#notes}}
    <div class="item"><span>{{.}}</span></div>
    {{/notes}}
</div>
```

This template expects to get the `userDetails` object as input. How to compile and render a given Mustache template with a given input depends on the Mustache implementation.